# How can I make my function run multiple times with different parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, var, onscroll

```js
var a = new scrollValues(0, 1000);
var b = new scrollValues(2000, 3000);

function scrollValues(start, end) {

  function Scrollbar() {
    var winScroll = window.pageYOffset - start;
    var height = end - start;
    var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;

    if (winScroll > 0 && winScroll < height) {
      document.getElementById("progressBar").style.height = scrolled + "%";

    } else {

      document.getElementById("progressBar").style.height = "0%";
    }
  }

  window.onscroll = function() {
    Scrollbar();
  };
}
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress-container {
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #d17524;
  width: 5px;
  height: 0%;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  min-height: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="progressBar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="scroll-video section">
</section>
```

I'm using the code above to create an animation like a video progress bar, but this one fills up when you scroll through certain parts of a webpage.
I want it to run multiple times at different points, but it only works for the last values I called (`var b = new scrollValues(40712, 43210);` in this case). I've tried multiple other ways to call the function, but it always either doesn't work or only uses the last mentioned values. What could cause this?

Comment: Why do you have `function Scrollbar() {...}` inside an enclosing function? I suspect there's something going on w/the scoping whereby `Scrollbar()` isn't visible outside the scope of the enclosing `scrollValues()` function. And I'm really not sure why you have it set up this way anyhow.

Comment: @Marc tbh that just happened when I was trying out all kinds of random stuff to see if I could get it to work.

Comment: @palaѕн I just added a demo my post!